# Conditional && fails to short circuit

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a simple conditional check to see if an object (call it model) has a has_many association with another object (call it association).

```
if model.respond_to? association.pluralize.to_s && !model.send(association.pluralize).nil?
  puts "Hello World"
end
```

Every time this check is called, rails throws an `undefined method` for that association on the model.

When debugging in the console, I tried to pick apart where the code is failing.

```
if model.respond_to? association.pluralize.to_s 
  puts "Hello World"
end
```

By removing the second half of the condition, it stops failing (and does not print, as expected).  Also checking `model.respond_to? association.pluralize.to_s` directly, always returns false.

So I tried again:

```
if false && !model.send(association.pluralize).nil?
  puts "Hello World"
end
```

And this works fine without any error and no printing (as I want).

So why, in the first set of code, does the conditional not short circuit? The first part always returns false, and yet the second half is still evaluated causing the `NoMethodError`. Is there some "gotcha" with `respond_to?` or `send` that is causing this? Or something simpler? Any help would be great thanks!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You have this error because this

```
if model.respond_to? association.pluralize.to_s && !model.send(association.pluralize).nil?
```

is equivalent to this:

```
if model.respond_to?(association.pluralize.to_s && !model.send(association.pluralize).nil?)
```

(`&&` has higher precedence than `respond_to?` method call).
If you want this to work correctly, use parenthesis:

```
if (model.respond_to? association.pluralize.to_s) && (!model.send(association.pluralize).nil?)
```

Comment: Such a simple solution thanks! I also have another check (that looks for has_one associations) right before this that is structured the exact same way (just less the `.pluralize`). Any idea why that never failed?

Comment: @jkeuhlen I don't understand your question. You mean you had the code version without calling `pluralize` and it worked?

Comment: Exactly. Which is why I was so confused. Exact same structure but on the singular version of the strings. They are set up as an `if elsif` but the first `if` never had the precedence issue.

Comment: @jkeuhlen maybe the string that `association` returns is already pluralized?

Comment: There are multiple strings that come from `association` (its a block variable) all are singular so `model.send(association)` should have a NoMethodError when the association is has_many if the code was consistent but it wasn't doing that. It isn't a huge deal just curious as to why it was inconsistent.

Comment: a slightly more idiomatic solution, in terms of parentheses usage and readability, might be `if model.respond_to?(association.pluralize.to_s) && model.send(association.pluralize).present?`

Answer (score 1):

This is an ambiguity in the condition statement, try:

```
if model.respond_to?(association.pluralize.to_s) && !model.send(association.pluralize).nil?
  puts "Hello World"
end
```